Environment Azure Devops - error on adding a new VM
I am trying to add a new resource to an existing environment. I already have multiple vm resources in it. But I am getting an error in adding a new on premise VM to it.
I run the powershell in the vm in admin mode. I get the script from devops when I click on Add New Resource to an existing Environment and select VM. ON executing it in VM's powershell which I want added as the resource creates a folder A2 in C:/azagent and then asks for tag and soon as I provide Tag value it returns the following error:
Error reported in diagnostic logs. Examine the log for more information.
    – C:\azagent\A2\_diag\Agent_20240729-073104-utc.log
Failed to add virtual machine resource. Linked environment pool is null.
Error adding agent. Try again or press CTRL+C to exit.

I went through logs saw a few Key not found messages and tried to install Java in the VM even after it I do not see any change in the error.

According to Manage VM resources in environments, you need to satisfy the following prerequisites.


Project Administrator or Build Administrator permissions in the Azure DevOps project that contains the environment.
Administrator role for the deployment pool, or set of target servers available to the organization.


The problem may be caused by insufficient permissions in your target Environment and Deployment pool. You can grant your account Administrator Role.

Environment permission

Assign your account Project Administrator or Build Administrator role of your target project.

Or assign your account Administrator role of your target Environment.
Go to Environments -> Select your target environment -> More actions -> Security -> Add user -> Search and select your account and assign Administrator role.




Deployment pool permission
Find the environment pool in the environment URL.

Go to Organization Settings -> Deployment Pools -> Find your pool based on the environment id -> More actions -> Security -> Assign your account Administrator role.



After that, copy a new registration script and check if it works as expected.

I do not see environment pool in the URL anywhere in the Organization -> Settings ->  Deployment Pools. Should there be a deployment pool with my VM as target server? Meanwhile, I am working to get my id added as an admin in the Environment.

If you can't see the deployment pool, assign your account Administrator role at deployment pool level from the Security button next to the New button. Then check if you can add a new VM resource successfully.

I can see the existing deployment pools. But I do not see the deployment pool based on environment id as you described in Step 2. I guess I will be able to get my name added as an admin unfortunately only by tomorrow or get hold of someone with the access. Will update soon as I get the required access and try adding the vm again.

The admin rights did it at the Deployment pool level. Thanks a lot, Ziyang Liu-MSFT

It's great to know my answer can help you.

The vm got added as resource in the environment but, when I am running the pipeline I get an error stating: Unable to deploy to the virtual machine 'vmname' as the machine is offline. The agent is running, I do not see any issue. Let me know if you have any suggestion or want me to raise this as a new question?

To focus on your new problem, it would be better to raise a new question.

Sure. Thank you, I will post after trying myself
